# Get a total count for all comments and display result

Tags: comments

I would like to find out the number of comments in total I have and display the number on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@stubudz:**

You are trying to make things easy on me today, right? :)

Here's what you need:

```
$comment_counts = get_comment_count();
echo $comment_counts['approved'];
//print_r($comment_counts); // Uncomment to see all from get_comment_count()
```

Comment: Also `wp_count_comments()` ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.3/wp-includes/comment.php#L789) ), this one caches results which makes a difference if this needs to be fetched several times or persistent object cache is used.

Comment: @Rarst - Good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$numcomms = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_approved = '1'");
if (0 < $numcomms) $numcomms = number_format($numcomms);
?>


There are <?php echo $numcomms; ?> in this blog.
```

source http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-display-the-total-number-of-comments-on-your-wordpress-blog